# creation of the profile editing view

Tags: django

hello everyone it's been a while since I haven't coded but I noticed some pref changes so I have some problem with the profile application edited the profile my code

views

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        user_form =UserEditForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        profile_form=ProfileEditForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user.profile ,files =request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()

       else:
            user_form=UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
            profile_form=ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

       context ={
           'user_form':user_form,
           'profile_form':profile_form,
       }
       return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',context)
```

form

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model=User
         fields=('username', 'email')

class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Profile
        fields=('description', 'image')
```

another try to see the same error

form

```
class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields=('username', 'email')
```

view

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
         form= EditProfileForm(request.POST,instance=request.user)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("/profile/")

        else:
            form=EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
            args={'form': form}
            return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',args)
```

error
The view accounts.views.edit_profile didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: you need to implement returning some response if request.method is 'GET'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says the view did not return a response.

Your `return render...` was indented under your POST method:

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
     # You need to define these before the POST method
     user_form=UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
     profile_form=ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    if request.method =='POST':
        user_form =UserEditForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        profile_form=ProfileEditForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user.profile ,files =request.FILES)

        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_form.save()
            profile_form.save()
            # I would return a success message here

        else:
            # Inform the user their form was not valid


     context = {
           'user_form':user_form,
           'profile_form':profile_form,
           }

     return render(request,'accounts/edit_profile.html',context)
```